# jquery comparing href + url and 'contains' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery here:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href*="' + window.location.href + '"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');

        //check that the text exists in the div and make top menu item bold
        $("ul#menu2 div:contains('About Us')");
        {
            $("ul.sf-menu li a:contains('About Us')").css('font-weight', 'bold');
        }
   });
```

The problem is onpage load the URL wont have anything but www.website.co.uk
The code is matching the url with the href in the menu and then making it bold.

When you click on a menu item its fine as the URL shows www.website.co.uk/aboutus/abgroup.apx

The 2nd part of the jquery checks a word in the left menu of one of the pages and then adds the style to the top menu which also matches that string. But it seems to be making all the top menu items bold.

Any ideas.

I need something like, on page load if URL contains .co.uk on the end then make the home `li a` bold.

**MENU MARKUP:**

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx">About Us</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/casestudies.aspx">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a 2 part question,

**1)** i need to stop the jquery making everything bold when the url is just www.website.co.uk as its failing on the compare with href and url.

**2)** need to know why on some pages the contains is highlighting all the time (this might be because i am not specific enough, i am using an ID to check but the top menu isnt.)

**This is my "About Us" menu:** 
(I also have services and sectors and the same principle applies - i want to search the div from the menu and make the top corresponding menu item bold.

```
<ul id="menu2">
    <div>About Us<br>
    </div>
    <li><a href="/en-us/aboutus/ABgroup.aspx" class="current">A&amp;B Group</a></li>
    <li style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="/en-us/aboutus/csr.aspx">CSR</a></li>
    <li style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="/en-us/aboutus/csr/sustainability.aspx">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="/en-us/aboutus/csr/healthsafety.aspx">Health &amp; Safety</a></li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/ab/aluminiumsheets.aspx">Aluminium Sheets</a></li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/ab/test.aspx">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/ab/cars.aspx">Cars</a></li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/ab/houseinteriors.aspx">House Interiors </a></li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/ab/abreports.aspx">A&amp;B reports</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your menu markup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving the first part is simple enough

```
var pattern = new RegExp('http(s?):\/\/(?:[\w-]+\.)?testsite\.co\.uk(/?)$');
if(pattern.test(window.location.href)) {
    $('.first').css('font-weight', 'bold');
} else {
    $('a[href*="' + window.location.href + '"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Having a `<div>` as a root element in a `<ul>` is invalid. I would reccomend if this is a heading, use a heading tag and put it before the `<ul>`. Something like this:

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<ul> .... </ul>
```

then you can do someting simple like so for the javascript:

```
var title = $('h2').text();
if(title !== '') $("ul.sf-menu li a:contains('" + title + "')").css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Comment: About Us is a heading in a left menu on a page. adding the menu to the question now.

Comment: Wow this works.. i changed it so its `<h6>` my only issue is when a user clicks a link to the case studies page it wont fire the code. I already have document.ready... Maybe i need a delay of 1 second?

Comment: case study url looks like this: http://cs.website.co.uk/en-us/casestudies/shopst3.aspx

Comment: The regex will only match the root url, something like `http://www.website.co.uk` or `http://cs.website.co.uk` we can change some things to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin [JAMES PADOLSEY regex selector for JQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)

And use like this:

```
var regexp_part = /\w+\.aspx$/.exec(window.location.href)[0];
if (regexp_part != null) {
    $('a:regex(href, ' + regexp_part[0] +'$)').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Comment: So if i load up, `www.website.co.uk` what will happen?

Comment: If change href attribute value to www.website.co.uk it will bold Home link

Comment: On page load it stops everything being bold which is good but it should make the "Home" `li a` bold so i need to check for the root url and then make it bold... any ideas on this? Then point 1 will be fixed.